# How to do query with `WHERE value IN list` in the Python Peewee ORM?

Tags: python, orm, flask, peewee

I'm using the (awesome) Python Peewee ORM for my Flask project, but I now got stuck trying to do a query with a `where value in ['a', 'b', 'c']`. I tried doing it as follows:

```
MyModel.select().where(MyModel.sell_currency in ['BTC', 'LTC'])
```

But unfortunately it returns all records in the DB. Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The [docs](https://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peewee/query_operators.html) has the answer: `x << y` will perform *x IN y, where y is a list or query*. So the final query will look like:

`MyModel.select().where(MyModel.sell_currency << ['BTC', 'LTC'])`

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance. I just found it after I posted this question.. :S Thanks a million anyway!

Comment: Python always coerces the return value of `x in y` to a boolean, necessitating the use of the `<<` operator.

Comment: @coleifer - Is there no way around this? Although it works now and I am capable of remembering it for next time, using `x in y` is so much more intuitive, especially for newcomers. And intuitive DB-usage is one of the things that Peewee shines with.. (thanks for creating peewee by the way; I've been using it for half a year now and it's awesome!)

Comment: It's a python thing, believe me I'd much rather use ``in``.  If you want, you can also write `MyModel.sell_currency.in_(['BTC', 'LTC'])`

Comment: Could you have some sort of intermediate object that implements __in__   (handwaves) along the lines of django F and Q objects?

Answer (score 5):

You can also do "IN" expressions with a subquery. For example, to get users whose username starts with "a":

```
a_users = User.select().where(fn.Lower(fn.Substr(User.username, 1, 1)) == 'a')
```

The `.in_()` method signifies an "IN" query

```
a_user_tweets = Tweet.select().where(Tweet.user.in_(a_users))
```

See http://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peewee/query_operators.html

Comment: From peewee.py, "in_ = _e(OP.IN)", "__lshift__ = _e(OP.IN)", the method "in_()" makes more sense for me. Thanks for your answer.