# Compare string with CharField with peewee?

Tags: python, sql, flask, peewee, flask-peewee

I'm trying to get a list of results where the given string `address` is in `models.Listing.address`. My code at the moment is:

```
@app.route('/search/<address>')
def search(address):
    results = models.Listing.select().where(address << models.Listing.address)

    return render_template('search.html', results=results)
```

For example I might pass in `39 Main Road` and would want it to select the records where `39 Main Road` is in the address field of a given listing (full address being `39 Main Road RICHMOND, NSW, Australia`)

However, my current code errors with: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'CharField'`

I've tried converting `models.Listing.address` to str but that just returns `unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'str'`

I would use `address in models.Listing.address` but as per [the docs](http://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#column-lookups) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179128/how-to-do-query-with-where-value-in-list-in-the-python-peewee-orm) it is neccesarry to use the `<<` operator.

Furthermore, i've tried using `address.in_(models.Listing.address)` which string doesn't have the property for...

Is it because i'm not comparing a CharField with a CharField? If so, how do I compare a string with a CharField? I've tried changing the CharField to a string but I can't use `in` with peewee because as @coleifer said in a comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179128/how-to-do-query-with-where-value-in-list-in-the-python-peewee-orm):

> Python always coerces the return value of `x in y` to a boolean, necessitating the use of the `<<` operator.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... as I was soon to find out:

`x << y` is for checking if the record x is in a list or query of records y

whereas the functionality I was trying to achieve is done by:

`.where(models.Listing.address.contains(address))`

So there you go, future me who will inevitably do this again ;)